# Approximating $Q^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x+1},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ for large $x$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The following function appears linear on `LogPlot`, what is the an elegant way to get a large-x series expansion?

```
expr = InverseGammaRegularized[1/(1 + x), 1/2];
LogPlot[expr, {x, 1, 10}]
Asymptotic[expr, {x, \[Infinity], 2}]
```

[image]

Background [q](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4707204/998) on math.SE

Comment: I don't know if this even helps, and I can't say it for certain because `Limit` won't work, but I suspect `Limit[D[Log[expr], x], x -> Infinity] = -Log[2]`. So `Log[expr]`$\approx$ `const - Log[2]x` for large x, or in other words, `expr` $\approx$ `const*2^-x` . Again, I can't confirm this suspicion, this is just from looking at values of `D[Log[expr],x]` for large x (by large x I mean x=99. , as mathematica won't output a result for me for x>99.).

Comment: I just saw there was a link to the math.SE thread and now I see this fact was already known, apologies

Answer (score 3):

A very good approximation for large $x$ is

$$
Q^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x+1},\frac12\right) \approx
\left(\frac12\Gamma\left(\frac{x+2}{x+1}\right)\right)^{x+1}
\text{ for $x\to\infty$}
$$
or, in simpler terms of $y=\frac{1}{x+1}$,
$$
Q^{-1}\left(y,\frac12\right) \approx
\left(\frac12\Gamma(1+y)\right)^{1/y} \text{ for $y\to0$}.
$$

Let's try it out:

```
f[x_] = InverseGammaRegularized[1/(1 + x), 1/2];
g[x_] = (1/2 Gamma[(x + 2)/(x + 1)])^(x + 1);

Plot[2^x*(f[x]/g[x] - 1), {x, 0, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 100,
     GridLines -> {{}, {Exp[-EulerGamma]/2}}]
```

[image]

We see that
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-1\approx\frac12 e^{-\gamma}\times2^{-x}
$$
meaning that the relative difference between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ decreases exponentially with $x$.

## update: generalization

More generally, for $0<q<1$ an excellent approximation is

$$
Q^{-1}(y,q) \approx [(1-q)\Gamma(1+y)]^{1/y}
$$
with exponentially small relative error for small $y$,
$$
\frac{Q^{-1}(y,q)}{[(1-q)\Gamma(1+y)]^{1/y}}\approx1+e^{-\gamma}(1-q)^{1/y}.
$$

It looks like [this is all well-known](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseGammaRegularized/06/01/03/0001/) to higher order.

Comment: Oh interesting! how did you get this form?

Comment: By looking at $h(y)=Q^{-1}\left(y,\frac12\right)$ for small $y$, fitting its series expansion numerically (like @UlrichNeumann suggests), and noticing that there's a pattern in the series coefficients, involving $\zeta(k)/k$, then using this pattern to sum the series expansion to infinity, and presto!

Comment: @Roman Very interesting answer! Which is your Mathematica version? With v12.2 I didn' t get the asymptotics of `f[x]/g[x]-1' .

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I have "13.2.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" but don't think this helps. A bit more concretely, with `h[y_] = InverseGammaRegularized[y, 1/2]` I looked at `Log[2^(1/y) h[y]]` for small $y$, fitting series-expansion coefficients by hand, and noticing that they look like $-\gamma+y\zeta(2)/2-y^2\zeta(3)/3+y^3\zeta(4)/4-y^4\zeta(5)/5+\ldots$. This series can be summed to infinity: `-EulerGamma - Sum[(-y)^k Zeta[k + 1]/(k + 1), {k, 1, ∞}]` gives `Log[Gamma[1 + y]]/y`, and so we have $\ln\left(2^{1/y} h(y)\right)\approx\frac{\ln\Gamma(1+y)}{y}$ etc.

Comment: @Roman Very clever, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately v12.2 doesn't evaluate the series expansion

Comment: @UlrichNeumann as I said, neither does v13.2.0 and I did it by hand by numerical fits, extracting one numerical coefficient at a time and asking Wolfram Alpha about closed-form expressions for the terms.

Comment: What's interesting in the series expansion of $\ln\left(2^{1/y}h(y)\right)\approx-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-y)^k\zeta(k+1)/(k+1)$ is that the omitted term $k=0$ is $\zeta(1)$, which diverges but can in many applications ("real" mathematicians, please stop reading here!) be replaced by its Cauchy principal value, which is just the Euler–Mascheroni constant $\gamma=$ `EulerGamma`, and so the whole series expansion becomes even nicer and can be started at $k=0$ by "redefining" $\zeta(1)=\gamma$. Funny how that works out.

Answer (score 1):

Take the values of the `LogPlot` and fit the data in the "log-space"

```
expr = InverseGammaRegularized[1/(1 + x), 1/2];
pic = LogPlot[expr, {x, 1, 10}]
xlogf = Cases[pic, Line[p_] :> p, -1] [[1]];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[xlogf , a - b x , {a, b}, x ,Weights -> -xlogf[[All, -1]] ]
Show[{pic,LogPlot[Exp[fit[x]], {x, 1, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed} ]}]
```

[image]

The original `expr` is asymtotic approximated too:

```
Plot[{ expr, Exp[fit[x]]}, {x, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> All,PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use the result of Lyon ([doi: 10.1371/journal.pone.0251626](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8118309/)) for the upper bound of the median of the gamma distribution:
$$
Q^{-1}(k,1/2)=\nu(k)\lessapprox \nu_U(k)\equiv 2^{-1/k} (e^{-\gamma} + k).
$$
Therefore

```
nU[k_] := 2^(-1/k) (E^-EulerGamma + k)
LogPlot[{InverseGammaRegularized[1/(1 + x), 1/2], nU[1/(1 + x)]}, {x, 1, 20}]
Simplify[nU[1/(1 + x)], Assumptions -> x > 1]
```

$$Q^{-1}\!\left(\frac{1}{x+1},1/2\right)\lessapprox 2^{-x-1} \left(\frac{1}{x+1}+e^{-\gamma }\right).$$

[image]